# Cannot download Azure Site Recovery Vault Settings File

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am having exactly same problem as mentioned on [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/81f62c50-ca3c-4175-ab0e-3f4fca88a31c/cannot-download-azure-site-recovery-vault-settings-file?forum=hypervrecovmgr). However, there is no proper solution posted in the answers.

I am trying to download ASR Vault settings file and getting below error in PowerShell.

```
Get-AzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile : Operation failed.
ClientRequestId: a1109cdc-4bc5-4107-a8a0-78a18763512345616-02-08 09:55:59Z-P
Cannot generate vault settings file for this vault. Download it from the Azure Portal.
At line:5 char:21
+ ... tingsFile = Get-AzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile -Location $VaultGe ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile], SerializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.GetAzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile
```

I am not trying to regenerate the Vault key. Just trying to download the file instead of downloading manually from Azure Portal.

Comment: I tried these two parameter sets but getting the same error with both: `Get-AzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile -SiteName ASRTestHVSite -SiteId 12345678-dbf5-4c96-8f5a-7a695ed36b24 -Path C:\ASR -Name ASRTestSRV -Location "East US 2"` and I also tried to use `Get-AzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile -Location $VaultGeo -Name $VaultName -Path $OutputPathForSettingsFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that that was a but in Azure PowerShell Module which automatically got resolved when I upgraded my Azure PowerShell version to 1.5.0.

Thank you for all the inputs though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the classic model or the resource manager model?
The cmdlet to download the vault key is Get-AzureRmRecoveryServiceVaultSettingsFile

Comment: Actually, that was a bug in Azure PowerShell earlier. It seems to be fixed now automatically. I am not getting that error any more. This has happened without any changes.